# Accessing Array Items: "For" loop works and "Foreach" gives System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, foreach, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to convert a For loop to a Foreach loop for my solution. While For Loop generates me the desired output (see below). Foreach generates the following error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

```
public static bool sumOfTwo(int[] a, int[] b, int v)
        {
            bool result = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i] + b[j] == v)
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
           return result;
         }
```

and my foreach implementation: What did possibly go wrong?

```
public static bool sumOfTwo(int[] a, int[] b, int v)
        {
            bool result = false;
            foreach (int i in a)
            {
                foreach (int j in b)
                {
                    if (a[i] + b[j] == v)
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: you're using the values inside the array "a" and array  "b" to index through the arrays, that's the problem. what you want is this -->  bool result = false;
            foreach (int i in a)
            {
                foreach (int j in b)
                {
                    if (i + j == v)
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            return result;

Comment: Also: just `return true;` in the `if()` condition. That will save you doing extra work once you've found a good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between them is that `for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)` is giving you an Index, while `foreach (int i in a)` is giving you the actual value.

E.g.: if you have an array `int[] a = {10, 0, 11}`, you'd get the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(a[i])

// a[0] = 10
// a[1] = 0
// a[2] = 11

foreach (int i in a)
    Console.WriteLine(a[i])

// a[10] = IndexOutOfRangeException
// a[0]  = 10
// a[11] = IndexOutOfRangeException
```

So rather than using Array Accessors in the second bit of code, you should be using the values of `i` & `j` directly:

```
....
        foreach (int j in b)
        {
            if (i + j == v)
                result = true;
        }
....
```

Comment: Also: just `return true;` rather than setting the result value. This gets the algorithm down from `n²` to `n log(n)`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn while accurate, it's beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

You implementation is completely wrong in the `foreach`
`foreach (int i in a)`
the `i` is the value of the array.
so if `a[0]` has a value of `10` but your array size is less than 10, you are literally calling `a[10]` in the if statement. You will have `out of bound exception`

just use 
`if (i + j == v)` in your if statement should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this down to a one-liner:

```
public static bool sumOfTwo(int[] a, int[] b, int v)
{
    return a.Any(A => b.Any(B => B + A == v));
}
```

The `Any()` method returns `true` iff a sequence has any members, or `false` otherwise. The rest of the code inside the call to `Any()` allows you to filter the sequence on some condition predicate, so you only get true if anything "survives" the filter.

For the condition, we again use the `Any()` method with the `b` sequence, effectively comparing every possible combination from `a` and `b`, just as the original code does, and limit the results to items that match our `a+b=v` condition. `Where()` could work for this, too, but `Any()` is better because it will stop at the first match.

I would prefer to use `.Intersect()` for this, which could result in code that's easier to understand, but the .`Intersect()` requires you to define a whole `IEqualityComparer` class rather than a simple delegate.